# Trace test or maximum eigen value in Johansen's cointegration test?

Tags: vector-error-correction-model

Which test to rely on for a time series data of 30 years for instance(when they offer different cointegrating equations in Johansen's cointegration test)? Trace test or maximum eigen value?

Say trace test says there are 8 cointegrating equations. Is this the number we input in the "number of cointegrating" box when estimating the VECM? Does it make a huge difference if we put 1?

Thanks!